# Confused about how java annotations (ie @SecurityDomain) work and what they do (do they generate xml? wsdl?)

Tags: java, soap, web-services, annotations

I have to admit that I am pretty confused how annotations work in java (SOAP) webservices.

What does adding a tag do?  I think that maybe adding a tag generates some xml or maybe a wsdl?  When I build should I see a difference in those files?

Any description or link would be great.  I have done a lot of searching but I think maybe I am searching for the wrong things.  For example when I search for:

```
@securityDomain
```

I just get garbadge results.  I am having difficulty finding a good description of what specific tags do as well as how tags in general work.

**Update**:

So is it safe to say that you can **either** use annotations or you can write your own xml/wdsl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@nnotations are defined by the Java language. An Annotation is a class. When you mark something with an annotation, the compiler and runtime arrange for an object of that class to be visible at runtime via java reflection.

The JAX-WS and JAX-B standards each define a raft of annotations. At runtime, or at java2ws(dl) time, they look at those annotations to decide what to do.

It looks to me as if @SecurityDomain in particular is part of JBoss, not any global standard, so you have to read the JBoss documentation to find out what it does.

I found [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2005/jw-0221-jboss4.html?page=3).

Comment: So is it safe to say that you can either use annotations or you can write your own xml/wdsl?

Comment: Sort of. In some cases you combine the two, and in some other cases you can use some other XML instead of @. Roughly, though, 'java-first' implies @nnotations, 'contract-first' implies writing xml.